how define a class problem in jMetalPy for multiobjective optimization
I m not very familiar with python but I write a code for two objective optimization using jMetalPy as follows:
from jmetal.algorithm.multiobjective.nsgaii import NSGAII
from jmetal.operator import SBXCrossover, PolynomialMutation
from jmetal.core.problem import FloatProblem
from jmetal.core.solution import FloatSolution
from jmetal.util.termination_criterion import StoppingByEvaluations
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def Shahab(X):
    Y1 = (X[0] - 2)**2
    Y2 = 1.0 / X[0] if X[0] != 0 else float('inf') 
    return Y1, Y2

class ShahabProblem(FloatProblem):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ShahabProblem, self).__init__()
        self.number_of_variables = 1  
        self.number_of_objectives = 2  
        self.number_of_constraints = 0  
        self.lower_bound = [0.1]  
        self.upper_bound = [5.0]  

    def evaluate(self, solution: FloatSolution):
        X = solution.variables
        Y1, Y2 = Shahab(X)
        solution.objectives[0] = Y1
        solution.objectives[1] = Y2

    def get_name(self):
        return 'ShahabProblem'

    def get_number_of_objectives(self):
        return self.number_of_objectives

    def get_number_of_constraints(self):
        return self.number_of_constraints

    def get_number_of_variables(self):
        return self.number_of_variables

    def create_solution(self) -> FloatSolution:
        return FloatSolution(self.lower_bound, self.upper_bound, self.number_of_objectives)

problem = ShahabProblem()

algorithm = NSGAII(
    problem=problem,
    population_size=100,
    offspring_population_size=100,
    mutation=PolynomialMutation(probability=1.0/problem.number_of_variables, distribution_index=20),
    crossover=SBXCrossover(probability=0.9, distribution_index=20),
    termination_criterion=StoppingByEvaluations(max_evaluations=25000)
)



I want to minimize Y1 and Y2 from Shahab(X) function, but when I run this code, an error occurs in line with "problem = ShahabProblem()" as follows:
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class ShahabProblem with abstract methods name, number_of_constraints, number_of_objectives


Can every one help me?
A code for multiobjective optimization in jMetalPy.
